# Restore all permissions on a sharepoint site Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, pnp-powershell

Restore all permissions on a sharepoint site, we have a sharepoint site that I have deleted several permissions at random and so I will need to restore the permissions **(go back to the 05/29/2021 authorization).**

Is it possible ?

Urgent plz !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my research, this is not possible in SharePoint online, it's necessary to recreate permissions on your site.